# Can't run ember server due to "Cannot find module 'promise-map-series'"

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I've been trying to run ember server but I keep getting the below error. I uninstalled and installed node and nvm and still can't get this thing to run. Any ideas?

`version: 0.0.46-master-5f2f0dc9cc
Cannot find module 'promise-map-series'
Error: Cannot find module 'promise-map-series'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Corvisa/ember-cli/foo/node_modules/broccoli-asset-rev/node_modules/broccoli-filter/index.js:9:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Corvisa/ember-cli/foo/node_modules/broccoli-asset-rev/lib/fingerprint.js:4:14)`

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: I also have this issue with ember cli 0.2.0